# How do I type a function, that wraps a promise returing function, and returns a type of the oringal function?

Tags: typescript

I am not sure if the title makes much sense, so I think it's better to show an example. The idea is, that this function, takes a 1 parameter, which is a promise returning function, and the wrapping function, will return an object, that will allow me to cancel the promise.

Here is what I have:

```
export interface ICancelablePromise<T> {
  cancel: () => void;
  promise: Promise<T>;
}

// Trying to create a type for the makeCancelable function
export type IMakeCancelable = <T>(promiseFunc: (a?: any, b?: any, c?: any) => Promise<T>) => ICancelablePromise<T>;

const makeCancelable = <T>(promiseFunc: Promise<T>): ICancelablePromise<T> => {
  let hasCanceled = false;

  const wrappedPromise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
    promiseFunc.then(
      (val: T) => (hasCanceled ? reject({ isCanceled: true }) : resolve(val)),
      (error: any) => (hasCanceled ? reject({ isCanceled: true }) : reject(error)),
    );
  });

  return {
    promise: wrappedPromise,
    cancel() {
      hasCanceled = true;
    },
  };
};

export default makeCancelable;
```

And here is a use case example:

```
const wrappedFetchApi = makeCancelable(fetchApi(SOME_URL));

wrappedFetchApi.promise.then(apiResponse => /* DO SOMETHING */);
```

OR

```
wrappedFetchApi.cancel();
```

As of now, with my typing I keep getting error:

**provides no match for the signature '(promiseFunc: (a?: any, b?: any, c?: any) => Promise): ICancelablePromise**

Comment: Could you prepare playground for it, i can not reproduce your error

Comment: I think right now you are inconsistent with your `promiseFunc`: Is this meant to be a function returning a Promise (as the name, your text and your type suggest) or a Promise (as `makeCancelable` and your use case example suggest)?

Comment: @StefanNeubert it's a function, that takes a function (that returns a promise), as a parameter, and returns an object, that has a promise: Promise<T> and cancle: () => void property.

Comment: @Amir if `makeCancelable` returns a promise how would you expect it to know what arguments to pass to the function that returns the promise? Also in the example code `makeCancelable` is actaully taking a promise and not function as `fetchApi(SOME_URL)` will return a promise. My suggestion would be to make `makeCancelable` a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)

Answer (score 1):

As Stefan Neubert mentioned, there is inconsistency in your code and I'm not exactly sure what you. But my best guess is you want to make a higher-order function that takes a `Promise` factory and returns a `ICancelablePromise` factory

So...

```
let delay = (ms: number) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
let delayCancellable = makeCancelable(delay);
delayCancellable(1000); // return a ICancelablePromise
```

Here's how you can do it...

```
interface ICancelablePromise<T> {
  cancel: () => void;
  promise: Promise<T>;
}

function makeCancelable<T, A extends any[]>(promiseFunc: (...args: A) => Promise<T>): (...args: A) => ICancelablePromise<T> {
    return (...args: A): ICancelablePromise<T> => {
        let hasCanceled = false;

        const wrappedPromise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
            promiseFunc(...args).then(
                (val: T) => (hasCanceled ? reject({ isCanceled: true }) : resolve(val)),
                (error: any) => (hasCanceled ? reject({ isCanceled: true }) : reject(error)),
            );
        });

        return {
            promise: wrappedPromise,
            cancel() {
                hasCanceled = true;
            },
        };    
    }
};

let delay = (time: number) => new Promise<{ test: string }>(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({ test: "foo" });
    }, time);
})
let delayCancellable = makeCancelable(delay);


let delayed = delayCancellable(1000);
delayed.promise
.then(val => {
    console.log(val.test)
    console.log(val.foo) // <-- error
})
.catch(() => console.log("rejected"))

delayed.cancel();

/*
all these will give compile error because
their args don't match delay's args
*/

delayCancellable()
delayCancellable("hello")

/*these will also give an error because they are
not promise returning functions*/

makeCancelable(() => alert("foo"))
makeCancelable(123)
```

Here's a [demo](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ICancelablePromise%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20cancel%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%20%20promise%3A%20Promise%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20makeCancelable%3CT%2C%20A%20extends%20any%5B%5D%3E(promiseFunc%3A%20(...args%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3CT%3E)%3A%20(...args%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20ICancelablePromise%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(...args%3A%20A)%3A%20ICancelablePromise%3CT%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20hasCanceled%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20wrappedPromise%20%3D%20new%20Promise%3CT%3E((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20promiseFunc(...args).then(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(val%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20(hasCanceled%20%3F%20reject(%7B%20isCanceled%3A%20true%20%7D)%20%3A%20resolve(val))%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(error%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20(hasCanceled%20%3F%20reject(%7B%20isCanceled%3A%20true%20%7D)%20%3A%20reject(error))%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20promise%3A%20wrappedPromise%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cancel()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hasCanceled%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20delay%20%3D%20(time%3A%20number)%20%3D%3E%20new%20Promise%3C%7B%20test%3A%20string%20%7D%3E(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resolve(%7B%20test%3A%20%22foo%22%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20time)%3B%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0Alet%20delayCancellable%20%3D%20makeCancelable(delay)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20delayed%20%3D%20delayCancellable(1000)%3B%0D%0Adelayed.promise%0D%0A.then(val%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(val.test)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(val.foo)%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20error%0D%0A%7D)%0D%0A.catch(()%20%3D%3E%20console.log(%22rejected%22))%0D%0A%0D%0Adelayed.cancel()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*%0D%0Aall%20these%20will%20give%20compile%20error%20because%0D%0Atheir%20args%20don't%20match%20delay's%20args%0D%0A*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0AdelayCancellable()%0D%0AdelayCancellable(%22hello%22)%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*these%20will%20also%20give%20an%20error%20because%20they%20are%0D%0Anot%20promise%20returning%20functions*%2F%0D%0A%0D%0AmakeCancelable(()%20%3D%3E%20alert(%22foo%22))%0D%0AmakeCancelable(123)) (You can also remove compile errors and hit Run to test the implementation)

Comment: Won't this work with generic rest parameters? (In Typescript 3, ofc)

Comment: @Cerberus how would you type it though? [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20testFn(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Afunction%20makeHof%3CA%2C%20B%3E(fn%3A%20(...args%3A%20A%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20B)%3A%20(...args%3A%20A%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20test%3A%20string%20%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(...args%3A%20A%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fn(...args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20test%3A%20%22yoo%22%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AmakeHof(testFn)(123)%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20no%20error%20) doesn't work.

Comment: @Cerberus is [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20testFn(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Afunction%20makeHof%3CA%20extends%20any%5B%5D%2C%20B%3E(fn%3A%20(...args%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20B)%3A%20(...args%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20test%3A%20string%20%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(...args%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fn(...args)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20test%3A%20%22yoo%22%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AmakeHof(testFn)(123)%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20error%20) correct?